# Flutter doesn't detect devices

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-devices

I've been using flutter for a few months with an Infinix phone and it worked fine. But I lost the phone. And now i'm trying to run an app on other devices. I enabled debug mode on both devices but flutter doctor says no devices.

[The computer shows 2 devices connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUJAq.png)

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.5-pre.28, on Microsoft Windows
>   [version
>       10.0.10240], locale fr-FR)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 28.0.3)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
>
> [!] Connected device
>       ! No devices available

Comment: Check adb drivers are installed correctly in your system for the devices.

Comment: You could try selecting a different "USB mode" on the devices. There's usually a notification you can tap one to change it."File transfer" always works for me.

Comment: Do you have Google USB Drivers installed?

Comment: I had Google USB Drivers installed since it worked fine with my previous device

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved !

Turns out I simply had to install the devices manufacturer's drivers.

Comment: Can you explain in more details

Answer (score 1):

**Check that your phone este en File Transfer Mode**

[image: transfer mode in android]

**Of course check on your notification panel have debug mode active**

[image: debug mode in android]

Comment: Yes the devices are on FTP and debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Turn On:

`Developer options -> USB debugging`